# Persisting the value randomly generated number using php

Tags: php

I am randomly generating numbers between 0 to 999 using shuffle function in php. Is there a way to persist that order of those randomly generated numbers on each page reload

Comment: Sounds like you're after [PHP sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['numbers'])) {
  $_SESSION['numbers'] = array(/*numbers here*/);
  shuffle($_SESSION['numbers']);
}

// use $_SESSION['numbers']
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this is what you're after, but I might be wrong here.

You can select the seed value used for random number generation using the `srand()` function. This is the initial number which is used to generate all other random numbers from successive calls to `rand()`. This means that if you pick a number (hell, even get one from `rand()`) and store it, you can then use `srand()` to seed the generator and gain the same sequence of values back out from `rand()`.